# SQL SERVER - Efficiently joining two tables using BETWEEN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, geolocation, inner-join

I've seen similar posts, however, no conclusive answers.

I am using geolite (free database) to lookup an ip block to a geo ip, and would like to do this in bulk-

The respective IP's are already converted into ipblocks, and sit a table ( L ).

Every ipblock falls within a range (between startIpNum and endIpNum), this sits in another table ( g ).

The query below works, however, is extremely inefficient especially since I need to perform this over a large time period -

```
SELECT l.ipAddress, g.locId
FROM l
INNER JOIN g ON l.ipblock BETWEEN g.startIpNum AND g.endIpNum
```

Both tables are indexed (g is compound indexed),

A HASH join cannot be performed since the join is made on a BETWEEN operator.

Is the only feasible option to restructure table g ? Or there another way?

Comment: What does "compound indexed" mean? On what columns? Also where does `b.locId` come from?

Comment: Also why would you think a hash join would be useful here?

Comment: thanks for your reply. translation from my native language :) i meant a composite index, not a compound index. this is done on  startIpNum and endIpNum

Comment: i just mentioned hash as i would have believed it would be more efficient in dealing was a large amount of data, as i am dealing with high volumes.

Comment: lastly, b.loc was a typo, this is now arranged.

Comment: I have read articles on this -

Comment: Just a thought: what kind of join shows in the query plan now?  If it's nested loop, maybe sorting L by ipblock would create a merge join which would perform a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

The best index for **a single query** is the one that has all columns in the `WHERE` / `JOIN` clause in its nodes, and all the columns in the `SELECT` clause are in the leaf (if not in the node already).

Try putting this index on table `l` and see if performance improves:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_l_ipblock ON l (ipblock) INCLUDE (ipAddress)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however unfortunately it is still very slow. I'd also like to add that the ipblock is a BIGINT, around 7-8 digits- i am not 100% sure if this will effect performance.

Comment: Can you quantity "slow", i.e.: how many seconds it's taking now and what your target for "good enough"? And how big are the `l` and `g` tables?

Comment: l table is 1,800,000 and g table is 2,000,000.

Comment: slow meaning 20 minutes to process 1 days (10k rows table l)